# Jasmine/Karma testing Angular 5 HTTP responses

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm totally new to TDD and I'm trying to debug a big Angular 5 application we're working in, at the company.

The app is working well, but now I have to implement tests, and I'm learning this stuff while I create the most basic and starter ones. I wrote this stuff already for the main module, just for trying this tooling:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let httpClientSpy: { get: jasmine.Spy }
  let dataReq: DataRequester;
  let queryBuilder: PanelQueryBuilder;
  let query: DataQuery;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MainComponent,
        Menu,
        MessageViewer
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        routing,
        AngularFontAwesomeModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ChartModule,
        Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule.forRoot(),
        NgbModule.forRoot()
      ],
      providers: [
        ReactiveService,
        DataRequester,
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();

  }));
  it('userType should be defined', async(()=>{
    expect(MainComponent.userType).toBeDefined();
  }))

  it('DataRequester exists and retrieves info', async(()=>{


    beforeEach(() => {
      // TODO: spy on other methods too
      httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get']);
      dataReq = new DataRequester(<any> httpClientSpy);
      queryBuilder = new PanelQueryBuilder();
    });



    expect(MainComponent).toBeDefined();
  }))
  it('1. Build query and check integrity', async()=>{
    query = queryBuilder.buildInitialQuery("panel", "conversions", 144);
    expect(query).toBeDefined();
  })

  it('2. Send query and check result', async()=>{
    dataReq.requestData(query, 'conversions').then( res => {
      expect(res).toContain("panel");

    })
  })
});
```

I want you to focus in one part: the DataRequester service. It's a service that has a method which returns a promise, and calls a specific part of our backend, returning the data. I just want here to check if this response object contains the property "panel", and the test...

...¡actually says it exists! But if I try to change the name of the property, to some non-existing property... it validates as true too. So maybe, the HTTP request is NOT working properly here, doing something wrong here.

Am I doing something bad in this code? Why doesn't the DataRequester "requestData" method execute properly, so Jasmine is able to properly test the conditions I want, in the response object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you"re doign something bad in your code. But don't worry, I did the same thing when I started.

First, you must understand the basics of *unit testing* : unit tests are made to prevent **side effects** in **a unit**.

Side effects are changes in a wanted behavior : for instance, you want to color a div in blue, and after some code editing, it colors red : this is a side effect.

A unit is the feature you're testing. In Angular, you can see which one it is with this :

```
describe('AppComponent'
```

Here, you're testing `AppComponent`.

Now that we settled this, let's go over what is wrong in your tests : you use **real instances of your services**. This means that you don't don't a single unit anymore : you're testing several units.

#### To correct that

You have to mock your services. You will check if your component is actually calling the service, and not if the service is calling your API (this will be checked by the unit test of the service itself).

In your test bed :

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    MainComponent,
    Menu,
    MessageViewer
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    routing,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ChartModule,
    Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule.forRoot(),
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ReactiveService,
      useValue : {}
    },
    {
      provide: DataRequester,
      useValue: {}
    },
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }
  ]
```

Usually, components handle only the view : you don't really to mock them (although you *should*).

This allows you to remove the `HttpModule`, which isn't required **in any test**.

You can also remove your routing module, because Angular provides a mock of it already : `RouterTestingModule`.

Your test bed becomes this

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    MainComponent,
    Menu,
    MessageViewer
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterTestingModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule,
    FormsModule,
    ChartModule,
    Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule.forRoot(),
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ReactiveService,
      useValue : {}
    },
    {
      provide: DataRequester,
      useValue: {}
    },
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }
  ]
```

Now you have a proper test bed.

All you have to do left, is add in the `useValue` of your mocks, **every service property used by your component with the correct signature**.

For instance, imagine your app component has this :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataRequester.requestWidth('URL').subscribe(res => this.reactiveService.width = res);
}
```

Then your test bed becomes this :

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    MainComponent,
    Menu,
    MessageViewer
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterTestingModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule,
    FormsModule,
    ChartModule,
    Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule.forRoot(),
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ReactiveService,
      useValue : {
        width: 0
      }
    },
    {
      provide: DataRequester,
      useValue: {
        requestWidth: () => of(100)
      }
    },
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }
  ]
```

(Values of the mock aren't important, you'll change them on demand)

As you can see, because your requester service returns an Observable, you are forced to return one too. And because your reactive service stores the width, you have to declare a variable of type number.

Now, in your test, using the previous example, you will do this :

```
it(`should get width from requester and store it in reactive service`, fakeAsync(() => {
  spyOn(component['dataRequester'], 'requestWidth').and.callThrough();

  component.ngOnInit();
  tick();

  expect(component['dataRequester'].requestWidth).toHaveBeenCalledWith('URL');
  expect(component['reactiveService'].width).toEqual(100);
}));
```

You declare what you do (test driven), you spy on your service (to see if it has been called), then you call through (because our mock is already an Observable and returns 100).

Then, you call the method to test, and flush the async calls out (`fakeAsync` and `tick` are part of Angular, you can find them in the docs about testing).

Finally, you make your expectations.

And with that, you successfully tested your first method !

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! Gotta give it a try now :) I'll check this as valid answer if everything works as expected!

Comment: The "RouterTestingModule" is available in Angular 5? This is a ng5 project and for now we can't upgrade it to 6

Comment: Yup, under `@angular/router/testing`, sorry I thought you would have intellisense

Comment: And I have in VisualStudioCode, but somehow it doesn't automatically detect that class. Could add it manually tho. Gotta tell you if it works in a while!

Comment: Where do you get the "component" keyword from? For me it appears undefined and have nothing to do with it

Comment: Sorry, it's called `app` in your case (but in other files it will be called `component`)